# Converting an ER diagram to relational model

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, entity-relationship

I know how to convert an entity set, relationship, etc. into the relational model.

What do I do when an entire diagram is given?

How do we convert it?

Do we create a separate table for each relationship, and for each entity set?

For example, if we are given the following ER diagram:

[image]

My solution:

Purchaser relationship and policies entity set

```
CREATE TABLE  Policies (
  policyid  INTEGER,
  cost  REAL,
  ssn  CHAR(11)  NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (policyid).
  FOREIGN KEY (ssn) REFERENCES Employees,
  ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Dependents weak entity set and beneficiary relationship

```
 CREATE TABLE Dependents (
  pname  CHAR(20),
  age  INTEGER,
  policyid  INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY (pname, policyid).
  FOREIGN KEY (policyid) REFERENCES Policies,
  ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

Employees entity set

```
 CREATE TABLE Employees(
   ssn Char(11),
   name char (20),
   lot INTEGER,
   PRIMARY KEY (ssn) )
```

Is my conversion true?

What are the steps for converting a complete diagram into relational model?

Are these the steps to follow?

- See whether there are any weak entities or key constraints. If there are, create a single table for this entity set and the related relationship. (Dependents with beneficiary and policies with purchaser in my case.)
- Create a separate table for the entity sets which do not have any participation or key constraints. (Employees in my case)
- If there are relationships with no constraints, create separate table for them.

So, every relationship and entity set in the diagram are included in a table.

What are the steps for conversion?

What do we do if there is only a participation constraint for a relationship, but no key constraint? Do we again create a single table for the related entity set and relationship?

Comment: Don't make SSN the primary key for Employees! They are re-used ~ 6 months after death. Also they can in rare circumstances (such as acquiring citizenship) change for a given person.

Comment: Also, recognize that a Primary Key constraint in the Physical Model is NOT an exact implementation of the Primary Key constraint in the Conceptual Design. The PK in the PM is (a) the means by which a physical representation of a record is updated in place; and (b) the handle by which a related Table efficiently verifies the existence of a physical record, and attaches to it. As a primary goal of the Physical Model is efficiency, making PK's in the PM short is an important design criteria; it is irrelevant in the Conceptual Design.

Comment: Then that is an error in the assignment, made by someone who has failed to do adequate research on SSN. It is a shame that every yahoo programmer who passed a SQL course feels competent to design databases. Designing a non-trivial database WELL is one of the most complex programming tasks one can tackle.

Comment: @yrazlik - I guess  It is better to use ON DELETE NO ACTION in place of CASCADE for the Policies table, which means no Employees could be deleted if Policies is pointing to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion and the steps that you have followed are correct. However from an implementation point of view there may be room for improvement. What you have implemented is more of a logical model than a physical model.

It is common practice to add a Surrogate Instance Identifier to a physical table. This is a general requirement for most persistence engines, and aids database efficiency. The value of the instance id, for example EmployeeId (INT), would be automatically generated by the database on insert. This would also help with the issue that a SSN is not a real world identifier so should not be a primary key. Add the Id as the first column of all your tables. I follow a convention of *tablename*Id.  Make your current primary keys into secondary keys (the natural key).

Adding the Ids then makes it necessary to implement a DependentPolicy intersection table:

```
DependentPolicyId, (PK)
PolicyId,
DependentId
```

You may then need to consider what is a natural key of the Dependent table.

You have age as an attribute; you should consider whether this the age at the time the policy is created or the actual age of the dependent, in which case you should be using date of birth.

Consider creation and modified dates.

I generally favor using the singular for a table, i.e. Employee not Employees.