# What does "Conversion of the ER diagram into a minimal set of relations" mean?

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, database-schema, erd

I am supposed to "Convert the ER diagram into a minimal set of relations". I have an ER diagram, not the best, but sufficient, which includes entities, attributes, relations, etc.

Am I supposed to convert to the relational schema or something else entirely?

Is what has been done here from their ER diagram into a set of create table statements based on relationships what I need to do?

[Converting an ER diagram to relational model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15890155/converting-an-er-diagram-to-relational-model)

Answer (score 0):

I know that a "minimal superkey" is a key which cannot have any less values and still work as a key. So maybe a minimal set of relations could mean it has to have just the information specified with no repeats or extra information?